# If the total number of terms in the expansion of $(a-b+2c)^n=45$, then $n=?$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Is there any specific formula for this because if there were two digits to expand then we can use the formula

$$\textrm{total number of terms} = n+1$$
But there are three digits to expand so i dont know how to do this 
Well this question has options and the options are

$$i) \   7 \\
ii)  \   8 \\
iii) \   9 \\
iv)  \  22$$

Comment: I assume you meant $(a+b+2c)^n$?

Comment: Hint:  First expand it as $\left(a+(2c-b)\right)^n$ which, as you point out, has $n+1$ terms.  Now expand each of those terms.  The one with $(b-2c)^0$ has one term.  The one with $(b-2c)^1$ has term terms, and so on.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a few cases:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & N \\
\hline
0 & 1 \\
1 & 3 \\
2 & 6 \\
3 & 10 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
? & 45 
\end{array}$$
Note that $N$ is a triangular number. So:
$$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=45 \Rightarrow n=9.$$